# How can I give a separate value to each index with the loc function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

It applies the last value obtained by putting the loc function into the for loop to all indexes in the index list.What I am trying to do is to assign different values ​​with each indexe for loop. I tried a lot but couldn't.

My unsuccessful attempt to give last for loop value to selected directories:

```
for val1 in index_list:
    for val2 in value_list:
        data.loc[val1 , 'VEHICLE_YEAR'] = val2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but perhaps you can achieve what you want by assigning the whole value list to your index-value desired combination:

```
data.loc[index_list, 'VEHICLE_YEAR'] = value_list
```

Comment: After finding the index of a data I want to do, change the data of another column in that index.I guess I haven't figured it out for a week :)